# Google Script Drive File Sizes to Spreadsheet - File Iterator Not Working

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to get a list of all the files I have in Google Drive into a Google Spreadsheet.  I'm using the following code:

```
function driveFileSizes() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var continuationToken = userProperties.getProperty('LOG_ALL_FOLDERS_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
  var start = new Date();
  var end = new Date();
  var maxTime = 1000*60*4.5; // Max safe time, 4.5 mins
  var file;
  var value=[];
  var values=[];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() +1;

  if (continuationToken == null) {
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  } else {
    var files = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken); 
  }

  while (files.hasNext() && end.getTime() - start.getTime() <= maxTime) {
    file = files.next();
    value[1] = file.getSize();
    if(value[1]>0){
      value[0]=file.getName();
      values.push(value);
    }
    end = new Date();
  }

  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);

  if(files.hasNext()){
    var continuationToken = files.getContinuationToken();
    userProperties.setProperty('LOG_ALL_FOLDERS_CONTINUATION_TOKEN', continuationToken); 
  } else {
    // Delete the token
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteProperty('LOG_ALL_FOLDERS_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
  }
}
```

The code runs and deposits data into the spreadsheet, however it is just the same file over and over (thousands of times).

What am I doing wrong?  It feels like the whole of the values array is being overwritten each loop.

This is bound to be me doing something stupid, but I can no longer see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your loop:

```
while (files.hasNext() && end.getTime() - start.getTime() <= maxTime) {
  file = files.next();
  value[1] = file.getSize();
  if (value[1] > 0) {
    value[0] = file.getName();
    values.push(value);
  }
  end = new Date();
}
```

You store the same object, `value`, in the loop, and assign to its properties (rather than it). Because your output is full of the same object, all references are updated together.

You can avoid this by pushing a new object each time:

```
var fs = file.getSize();
if (fs > 0) {
  values.push([file.getName(), fs]);
}
```

If you want, you are able to declare the `fs` variable outside the loop and still use it properly, because the whole object is assigned to, rather than a property of it.